# Files dont check out using BitBucket in VS2010

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, bitbucket

I just created an account at BitBucket for my Visual Studio 2010 project's source control.  Everything seems to be setup fine.  I can see my project and file on BitBucket.  All my files in VS have a "Locked" icon near them and when i go to the project files context menu, I have all the options available for GIT .

The problem is, though, that the files wont check out when I edit them.  I don't get any error but the files "locked" icon never change to the "check mark" icon.  Also, when I go to File menu, I would expect the Source Control sub menu, but that's not there either.  If I change my  Source Control provider to Visual Studio Team Foundation, then that option under File becomes available but not when my Source Control provider is Git Source Control.

Anyone know what's going on or how to fix this?

thanks
jason

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems restarting my PC was what it took.